# Max Value Per Row from a set of 100 Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, return-value, row, max

While I have seen several answers to this question all of them tend to rely on on the greatest function which keeps coming back with a

"Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'GREATEST' is not a recognized built-in function name."

I would like to know a way to build a query that for each row returns the artifact id, and the greatest value in the row along with the column it was in. Any suggestions would be welcome. I've looked over quite a few example on this board and others but keep runnign across various errors.

Attempted and Failed Code, shortened for veiwing pleasure:

```
SELECT artifactID, GREATEST(V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6...V98,V99) AS col_value,        
    CASE GREATEST(V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6...V98,V99)         
        WHEN V0 THEN '0'          
        WHEN V1 THEN '1'          
        WHEN V2 THEN '2'          
        WHEN V3 THEN '3'
        ...     
              WHEN V99 THEN '99'
        END AS col_name 
    FROM dbo.Theta
```

Example of what I would like query to return:

```
ArtifactID  GreatestColumnValue  ColumnValueCameFrom
00001            .330                   59
00002            .89                    89
...             
01000            .44                     7
```

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: @Lamak - `dbo.Theta`... and `Msg, Level`.. SQL Server I guess

Comment: / hope you are using SQL Server 2005+, otherwise.. a much longer answer will be needed :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.artifactID, c.col_value, c.col_name
FROM dbo.Theta t
OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM (
        SELECT '0', V0 UNION ALL
        SELECT '1', V1 UNION ALL
        --...
        SELECT '99', V99) X(col_name,col_value)
    ORDER BY col_value desc) C
```